Rewriting the system $x'=\sqrt{|y|}+x^2+h(t)$, $\;y'=e^x+y$ in an equation of second order

I have to rewrite the system of
$$\begin{align}
x' &= \sqrt{\left|y \right|} + x^{2} + h(t)\\ 
y' &= e^{x} + y
\end{align}$$
in an equation of second order.

I know that I have to find $ x'' $ from the first equation and replace the $y'$ that will appear in this new equation. After replacing $y'$ (I can find it from the second equation), I have to find $y$ from the first equation ($y =  ...$) and replace it, as well.
So in the end a have a final equation without $y$, only with $t,x,x',x''$
But in this exercise I have $\left|y \right|$ instead of $y$.I know how to find the derivative of  a function $\left|y(t) \right|$ , but how can I replace $y$ if I know $\left|y \right|$? Should I assume that $y$ is positive/negative?

You can use the second equation instead. Starting from $x = \log(y'-y)$,and, consequently, $x' = \dfrac{y''-y'}{y'-y}$, you replace in the first equation obtaining
$$
\dfrac{y''-y'}{y'-y} = \sqrt{|y|} + (\log(y'-y))^2 + h(t).
$$

Thanks for your answer. It's much easier this way. But we still have a $\left| y\right|$ in the final equation. I guess that this is not a problem, we don't have any more clues to make the equation easier.
I tried my way and I found this
$x'' = \frac{e^{x}y + \left|y \right|^{2}}{2\sqrt{\left|y \right|} \left|y \right|} + 2xx' + h'$
So I get from the first equation that $ \sqrt{\left|y \right|} = x' - x^{2} - h(t)  $ or $\left| y\right| = (x' - x^{2} - h(t))^{2}$. Can I use that $y = \pm (x' - x^{2} - h(t))^{2}$ and replace all of them?

Thanks @PierreCarre for your help.
I get the second equation $y' = e^{x} + y$ . So $$y'' = e^{x} \cdot x' + y'$$ Replacing $x'$ I get $$y'' = e^{x} \cdot (\sqrt{\left|y \right|} + x^{2} + h(t)) + y'$$ and from the second equation I have $$y' = e^{x} + y \Rightarrow e^{x} = y' - y \Rightarrow x = \log(y' - y)$$ Finally, I get $$y'' = (y' - y) \cdot (\sqrt{\left|y \right|} + (\log(y'-y))^{2} + h(t)) + y' $$
